# How can we check the available physical memory to set it as a variable in Makevars?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am currently trying to incorporate a C++ library into an R package to expose its functionality. The original C++ library used Cmake, where multiple variables were set. I am trying to avoid using Cmake and am trying to make my way through writing a new Makevars file. However, one of the variables defined through the original Cmake setup was the available physical memory, through `cmake_host_system_information`.

Is there any recommended way to retrieve the available physical memory to then define it in Makevars?

Comment: Hardware information access tends not to be portable across operating systems. Available memory may also differ between _compile-time_ and _run-time_ so it does not make a lot of sense.  But the easiest answer may be that you _can_ use `cmake` if you want to (and declare the dependency) -- see [Writing R Extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks a lot for pointing me to that possibility! This is indeed being very helpful. I see the point about the problems with using available memory as a variable in compile-time, will certainly work towards alternatives...